# Android Espresso testing ProgressBar visibility GONE before assert

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to test a spinner that should display while loading the information from an API.
The problem is that I can't assert the initial state VISIBLE because it disappear too fast when the results are emitted back thus always having a failing test

`Expected: (view has effective visibility <VISIBLE> and view.getGlobalVisibleRect() to return non-empty rectangle)`

`Got: view.getVisibility() was <GONE>`

The first attempt using ui-automator

```
@Test
    fun displayLoaderWhileFetchingPlaylistDetails() {
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(idlingResource)
        uiObjectWithId(R.id.playlist_list).getChild(UiSelector().clickable(true).index(0)).click()
        val spinner = uiObjectWithId(R.id.playlist_details_loader)
        assertTrue(spinner.exists())
    }
```

Another variant for the test without ui-automator

```
@Test
    fun displayLoaderWhileFetchingPlaylistDetails2() {
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(idlingResource)
        onView(
            allOf(
                withId(R.id.playlist_image),
                isDescendantOfA(withPositionInParent(R.id.playlist_list, 0))
            )
        )
            .perform(click())
        assertDisplayed(R.id.playlist_details_loader)
    }
```

ui-automator helper

```
fun uiObjectWithId(@IdRes id: Int): UiObject {
        val resourceId = getTargetContext().resources.getResourceName(id);
        val selector = UiSelector().resourceId(resourceId)
        return UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation()).findObject(selector)
    }
```

Fragment

```
private fun observeLoaderState() {
        viewModel.playlistLoader.observe(this as LifecycleOwner) { playlistSpinner ->
            when (playlistSpinner) {
                true -> playlist_details_loader.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                else -> playlist_details_loader.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
class PlaylistDetailViewModel(
    private val repository: PlaylistRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val playlistLoader = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    fun getPlaylistDetails(playlistId: String) = liveData {
        playlistLoader.postValue(true)
        emitSource(
            repository.getPlaylistDetailsById(playlistId)
                .onEach { playlistLoader.postValue(false) }
                .asLiveData()
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a rule using ActivityScenarioRule.

in example:

```
@get:Rule
val mActivityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```

**ActivityScenarioRule**, which is a **JUnit** rule used for functional testing of Android activities. The purpose of this rule is to launch the specified activity (MainActivity in this case) before each test method runs and handle its lifecycle during the test. 
Then you can write the test code for the display as below:

```
@Test
fun displaysLoaderWhileFetchingThePlaylist() {
    mActivityRule.scenario.onActivity {
        assertDisplayed(R.id.pbLoader)
    }
}
```

The **mActivityRule.scenario** property returns an instance of **ActivityScenario**, which represents the current state of the activity under test. The ActivityScenario provides various methods to interact with the activity, such as launching, finishing, or monitoring the state of the activity.
**onActivity** executes a specific action in the main thread of the current Activity.
As a result, **mActivityRule.scenario.onActivity** is used to safely perform UI interactions in test code and ensure that these interactions are executed in the main thread. 
I hope this answer will solve your problem.

Comment: Tks, this took me out of a failing test scenario on an old course.

Answer (score 0):

In Android when you set a View's visibility to GONE the renderer does not draw the View object, so the View practically has no dimensions. The same applies if you call any function that searchs in the UI tree for the View that has visibility set to GONE, and will return no match. If your only goal is to pass the test, my suggestions would be to set the View to INVISIBLE instead of GONE or to change the way you test for that specific layout.
From Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

- View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for
  layout purposes.
- View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space
  for layout purposes.